# Google BigQuery logs: queries I do not recognize - ghosts in my boxes?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am really new to Google cloud technologies and BigQuery. I have been monitoring our trial instance usage and billing and saw that the bill increases every day by 20-30 GBPs. Looking closer at the logs, I can see a query that makes no sense to me:

- The SQL makes absolutely no sense nor I remember writing it... Uses `GROUP EACH BY` which is news to me
- Uses partition times: `_PARTITIONTIME >= TIMESTAMP('20170306') AND _PARTITIONTIME <= TIMESTAMP('20170608'))` which I would never use (too long and in the future)
- Uses table name `t0` - I tend to reference the table as `nf` in all my queries
- <s>Runs random times (so it is not scheduled in cron or something)</s>
- Fails with "Resources exceeded during query execution." on stage 3
- Re-runs ~3mins after the first failure (double-tapping!) and then disappears for some hours (maybe a day in some cases)
- I cannot see `callerIP` in `requestMetadata` in the logs
- It *does* have my email address in `authenticationInfo.principalEmail` (from UI) and `user_email` (from `bq show -j`)
- It appears as `job_` in `bq ls -j` as opposed to `bqjob_` or `bquijob_`
- Runs for almost a week now
- Run this morning at 1:48 ... I am sure I was asleep and my sleep-walking skills are not good enough to boot my laptop and type that query!
- Unfortunately it accesses our largest field (IPv6) and thus I believe it charges us a lot

What I have tried:

- Clear browser caches
- Reboot my desktop (the only machine on at 1:48) to get rid of any hanged processes
- Check my google account security and everything seems in place
- *BANNED* myself from the project to see if this will reappear or not (I have to rely on colleagues now for UI - I can still use bq from a server)

Questions:

- What is `job_` where can it be submitted from if it is not via `bq` or `bqui`?
- Is there a way to see which box submits the job? There should be an IP somewhere?
- Could I have possibly scheduled that query to run on Google Cloud itself (given missing `callerIP` field from the logs)?
- Can `jobs` hang in GC or echo or something?
- Any other ideas (other than sleep walking that is!)

I really have no clue how to troubleshoot this ...

#### UPDATE 1

There seems to be happening every ~12hours, output of `bq ls -j -a -n 4000 | grep FAILURE | grep ' job_' | grep -v '0:00:00'`:

```
job_gMFDrHsT291qb_GbWtE2LJcLjXc              query      FAILURE   08 May 14:36:04   0:01:07   
job_NyjyB18-fmBwgwd54TPrCjZAoNg              query      FAILURE   08 May 14:32:57   0:01:05   
job_li4-HVdwTmkFXWD73U5AeRKCDUc              query      FAILURE   08 May 01:49:21   0:00:19   
job_4pJageclv07PGjwDHrY81Eaj7mc              query      FAILURE   08 May 01:47:01   0:00:18   
job_tbuCj0TW8e3AOp2VQBQK4gglYS0              query      FAILURE   07 May 13:11:05   0:00:18   
job_yL5f6p15iEJKTZ-fp1jjDCJJyjo              query      FAILURE   07 May 13:08:20   0:00:43   
job_kY068APnwe5O4S4byne6bcqmYBM              query      FAILURE   07 May 00:27:52   0:00:17   
job_CezXvXKBgus-RdvbFFVsYfDcjEo              query      FAILURE   07 May 00:25:30   0:00:18   
job_S2b0y5RI6q1piYOVmPT_oMWAoN0              query      FAILURE   06 May 11:58:57   0:00:46   
job_HrJ_tcGAFoLuJPUgQ7oX9EAc2K0              query      FAILURE   06 May 11:56:17   0:00:38   
job_EHJGgzPm4nU5BXaAZmcYhzjgA20              query      FAILURE   05 May 23:19:30   0:00:17   
job_uusSrZ2egHSz746oa8AP663tmQI              query      FAILURE   05 May 23:16:47   0:00:41   
job_Y0V1Qvs0VS30RDuMejyj7ZPvK2s              query      FAILURE   05 May 10:42:55   0:00:16   
job_dPo0DWsAhQ7q84-hnijLTIGYYkI              query      FAILURE   05 May 10:40:36   0:00:18   
job_ve1yBjCDsjP5LMSeGV1bFza-Cx4              query      FAILURE   04 May 22:16:52   0:00:28   
job_1JnBDvDCPt8MkIMwfyzB4UmWSCo              query      FAILURE   04 May 22:14:30   0:00:20   
job_rG9UKl4qZ0p5T3AtXzH9hcDpafQ              query      FAILURE   04 May 09:22:15   0:00:19   
job_haQ-YE1nBb38_l9yvV1Qv4e0QKo              query      FAILURE   04 May 09:19:52   0:00:21   
job_PTPYDrppI02Noei67nSfjSpKa6E              query      FAILURE   03 May 20:41:16   0:00:17   
job_6mhiAbIkAFXaKMBF_aguy8NPOGY              query      FAILURE   03 May 20:38:54   0:00:20   
job_wq3yV1lGsXx_GGsuJJETGkrPgmQ              query      FAILURE   02 May 17:34:40   0:01:03   
job_ljTZeVt1yr-23faNNHPgutVRXdw              query      FAILURE   02 May 17:32:15   0:00:20   
job_LSFjN3oEM2UztrYxywnZWv-xHpw              query      FAILURE   02 May 12:25:14   0:00:13   
job_7G0_gZJx6uSYwU__lmMpWyuJtZ4              query      FAILURE   02 May 12:22:39   0:00:19   
job_7hFsQlIgMluj2iouPA-CKj2hxnE              query      FAILURE   02 May 12:22:34   0:00:19   
job_bJ_jRxkfWLggxcYHFBLE71rGB50              query      FAILURE   02 May 12:22:27   0:00:21
```

Comment: are you using any 3rd party tools?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: No only `bq` and a small javascript page I wrote myself using `gapi`

Comment: Possibly datastudio, with a dashboard/report authorized to run using your credentials?  You may be observing datastudio attempting to prefetch cache data every 12 hours.

Comment: @shollyman: !!! You are a star!!! I would have never found it... it is one of the visualization solutions I was looking into but required views so I dropped it. The testing dashboard was still active and I had completely forgotten about it. Make your comment an answer (would also be good to explain the 12 hours pattern and/or why there is no `callerIP`) and I will upvote and accept :)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: Sorry for my misleading comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datastudio has the ability to use embed your credentials to power visualizations/reports.  There's also a capability in datastudio known as [prefetch caching](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039#prefetch-cache) which will issue queries on a regular interval (typically 12 hours).  The lack of `CallerIP` in the log may indicate the request(s) have been issued from another Google service, rather than from a request with an external origin.